# Why are there 2 forward slashes in sed command before g keyword?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

For the below code:

```
sed "s/ //g" filename
```

Since, this is used to remove the spaces, why there are 2 forward slashes in front of 'g'. What can be the reason. Though it is working fine.

Comment: It replaces a blank by nothing globally on the line — effectively deleting all the blanks.  The operation or command is the `s/…/…/` (substitute) command; the `g` is a modifier (meaning repeat the search after each pattern is found, starting after the end of the replacement text).  The search pattern (a blank) is between the first and second slashes; the replacement pattern (an empty string) is between second and third slashes.

Comment: `tr -d ' '` would be also an option.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you read some [tutorial](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html) about sed first.

Long story short, use this example `sed "s/search_pattern/replace_string/g" filename`:

- `s` means search and replace
- `search_pattern` is the pattern to be searched
- `replace_string` is the string to be replaced
- `g` means apply the action globally, which means keep search and replace for all match pattern

Thus, `sed "s/ //g" filename` means search all space in file and replace it to empty string

Answer (score 1):

Each slash is a token, there's just nothing between them. For example if you wanted to replace spaces with underscores, you would put an underscore between the second and third slashes:

```
sed "s/ /_/g" filename
```

Example run:

```
$ echo "foo bar" | sed "s/ /_/g"
foo_bar
$ echo "foo bar" | sed "s/ //g"
foobar
```